# Create Spark RDD procedurally

Tags: apache-spark

I need to create a Spark `RDD` (or `DataFrame`, either is fine), by repetitively calling a custom function that will generate records one by one. Is it possible?

There is no file I can read from because I am interfacing with another system that manages a complex pipeline to produce the records, AND the file generated would be too big anyway (hundreds of TB) for us to consider persisting to disk.

Comment: I am not sure if I got your problem completely but you can solve this problem using streaming where you can have your custom receiver( which has custom function) that will generate records then at streaming end you will get DStreamRDD.

Comment: Let me look into that - might be just what I need. Thanks! :-)